# How do I define a route to a file that is inside another folder in Views?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty new to Laravel and I'm stuck on this silly little error so I would really like for someone to help me out here. As the title suggests, I'm trying to route a file called 'admin' that is inside a 'dashboard' folder in Views. My Web.PHP looks like:

```
  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(["prefix" => "dashboard"], function() {
Route::resource('/admin','DashboardController');
});
```

and my DashboardController's index() function is:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('dashboard/admin');
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in documentation, you should use "." separator instead of "/".

```
public function index(){
   return view('dashboard.admin');
}
```